# Dynamically create number of buttons with specific value to function

Tags: html, typescript, ionic2, components, innerhtml

How it is possible in `Type Script` `Ionic2` application:

If I have  `btnNmb: number;` for example, with current value `9`, then dynamically create `9` buttons on `home.html` form, and attach each number from this particular range `9` to each generated button for `button1` `value` `=1`, for `button2` `value` `=2` etc., to pass this `value` in function `fnc(value)` and assign it to `this.x` variable with click from dynamically created button inside this  `fnc(value) { this.x = value; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*ngFor` to achieve this, but ngFor needs an array or any object with iterable interface, so heres what you can do:

in your TypeScript file:

```
export class YourClass {
  public x = number;
  public btnNmb: number = 9;
  public btnsArray: Array<number> = []; // You need to initialize it so your template doesn't break

  constructor () {
    // You can call it here or on ionViewDidLoad() lifecycle hook
    // Or if the btnNmb is a dynamic number you can call it again when the value changes
    this.generateNumberArray();
  }

  // You need to iterate from 1 to the number given in the btnNmb property
  generateNumberArray = () => {
    for(var i = 1; i <= this.btnNmb; i++){
      this.btnsArray.push(i);
    }
  }

  // The function that's triggered by button click
  fnc = number => this.x = number;
}
```

then in yout html you'll use `ngfor` to itare through array and display a number of buttons

```
<button ion-button *ngFor="let nmb of btnsArray" (click)="fnc(nmb)">{{nmb}}</button>
```

Here's the [NgFor docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) if you need more information. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, sorry for late answer, useful example, thank you